# C# How can I add a parameter to my Http request?

Tags: c#, oauth

I am trying to create a Logout function for a console application that is using OAuth 2.0. However, when I call my function the response is:

```
{
  "error" : "invalid_token"
}
```

Following this [information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post), this is how I make the Http Request:

```
var values = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "token", token.Token } };
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var response = 
    await client.PostAsync("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke",content);

var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Log.Info(responseString);
```

[Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer) says:

> To programmatically revoke a token, your application makes a request to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke and includes the token as a parameter:

`curl https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token={token}`

> 

The token can be an access token or a refresh token. If the token is an access token and it has a corresponding refresh token, the refresh token will also be revoked.

> 

If the revocation is successfully processed, then the status code of the response is 200. For error conditions, a status code 400 is returned along with an error code.

Someone pointed out that the first parameter of `PostAsync` should be `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=`. However, when I tried I received the following response:

```
{
  "error" : "invalid_request",
  "error_description" : "Missing required parameter: token"
}
```

Because of the difference in error messages, I feel like I am passing the token when it is `"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke"`, or I at least got the parameter part down, but am not certain I am correct.

Are there any glaring errors that maybe the source of the problem?

#### Update:

Is it also possible to see the status code in the response message?

Yes when I print out `response.StatusCode` I see the return being `BadRequest` meaning it is something syntactically wrong with the request.

After Reading [RFC Documentation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7009) :

> The client constructs the request by including the following parameters using the `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` format in the HTTP request entity-body:

....

> 

For example, a client may request the revocation of a refresh token
with the following request:

> 

```
 POST /revoke HTTP/1.1
 Host: server.example.com
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
 Authorization: Basic czZCaGRSa3F0MzpnWDFmQmF0M2JW
```

> 

```
 token=45ghiukldjahdnhzdauz&token_type_hint=refresh_token
```

After reading this they recommend using POST but didn't say it was necessary, and that the second parameter `token_type_hint` is OPTIONAL.

However, the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` part is what I don't understand. Can someone clear up what this is?

Comment: I would use a web debugging proxy http://www.telerik.com/fiddler (there are other options) to see the actual requests and responses being sent.  This way you can see if you're getting what you think you're getting.  Then please update your question w/ that additional detail.

Answer (score 0):

The examples on the Google (Ruby) use a GET request instead of a POST.  I would try switching to [HttpClient.GetAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158944(v=vs.118).aspx).  Roughly:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var response = 
    await client.GetAsync("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=" + HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode(token.Token));

var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Log.Info(responseString);
```

Comment: Ok so I cannot get `System.Web.HttpSeverUtility`, I think it may have turned into `System.Net.WebUtility`, anyways substituting that in yields `"error" : "invalid_token"` like before. I believe that it is passing the parameter. I am unsure on how the google part of it works, the part of the token that is being passed is just the token field. That could be the issue, but if it is, I am unsure how to concat all the fields together in the right format....

Comment: OK, I still think using Fiddler to trace the request would be helpful.  You should tweak your access token before posting.

Comment: For some reason fiddler causes the app to crash when trying to submit requests...